# Number guessing game, relationship between maxGuesses and guess count is skewed by 1

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to let the game only let the user have 3 guesses to guess correctly.  The problem is that it lets the user guess a 4th time, but even if user guesses correctly on 4th attempt I get a wrong answer message.  I tried changing the number of guesses, changing that i = 0 start position, subtracting one from maxGuesses in the for loop.  No matter what I try the relationship is off by one.  Here is my code so far.

```
let readlineSync = require("readline-sync");
let hint = "";
let maxGuesses = 3;
const maxRange = 10;
const minRange = 1;
let userGuess = readlineSync.question(
  "I have chosen a number between " +
    minRange +
    " and " +
    maxRange +
    ". You have " +
    maxGuesses +
    " tries to guess it!\n"
);

const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxRange + 1);


function handleGuess(userGuess) {
    if (userGuess != null && userGuess != undefined && (userGuess <= maxRange && userGuess >= minRange)) {
      for (i = 0; i <= maxGuesses - 1; i++) {
        if (userGuess == randomNumber) {
          console.log(userGuess + " is CORRECT! YOU WIN!");
          return;
        } else {
          if (userGuess > randomNumber) {
            hint = "Think lower you fool.";
          } else {
            hint = "Think higher you fool.";
          }
          console.log(hint);
          userGuess = readlineSync.question("Guess again. \n");
        }
      }
      console.log("Dude...YOU SUCK!");
      return;
    } else {
      userGuess = readlineSync.question("Fix your answer fool! \n");
      handleGuess(userGuess);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your first call is `handleGuess()` with no parameter.
Then, your program asks the user for its **first** guess (withe the message "Fix your answer fool!"). If you call `handleGuess()` with a parameter, the following still applies.

After that, the loop will begin.

if the first answer is wrong, the console will display the message "Think [higher/lower] you fool.", and then request the **second** guess. Still in the first loop iteration.

Do you see where the problem is ?

If the second guess is still wrong, the console will display the second wrong message and request the third guess while still being in the second loop iteration.

Finally, If the third guess is still incorrect, the third "wrong" message will appear and your code will request a **fourth** guess before ending the loop and display the message "Dude...YOU SUCK!" without verifying your input.

To prevent that, you can do something like this :

```
function handleGuess(userGuess) {
    i = 0;
    do {
        if(i > 0) {
            if(userGuess > randomNumber) {
                hint = "Think lower you fool.";
            } else {
                hint = "Think higher you fool.";
            }
            console.log(hint);
            userGuess = readlineSync.question("Guess again. \n");
        }
        while(isNaN(userGuess)) {
           userGuess = readlineSync.question("Correct you guess. \n");
        }
    } while(userGuess != randomNumber && i < maxGuesses);
    if (userGuess == randomNumber) {
        console.log(userGuess + " is CORRECT! YOU WIN!");
    } else {
        console.log("Dude...YOU SUCK!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just set the condition for your loop to be `i < maxGuesses` not `i <= maxGuesses -1`:

```js
var maxGuesses = 3; 
for (i = 0; i < maxGuesses; i++) {
  console.log("Guess " + (i + 1));  // Only adding 1 here so output is 1-based
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, that is what I had originally but it still allows me to make a 4th guess and then returns wrong answer message regardless of answer being correct or not.

Comment: That is why i ended up adding the i <= maxGuesses -1  to it to see if that would fix it somehow.